# Custom return codes in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to return codes like `0-success,` `4-warning`, `8-failure`.
Shell has only two return codes i.e `0` and 1. Is it possible to have above custom code? For success I need 0 and for failure I need 8.

Comment: Shell does not gave only two return codes ? Try `bash -c 'exit 123' || echo $?` in a shell and observe that the status code 123 in returned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a false assumption.

Comment: if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo -e "Parameter file Successfully loaded\n return code=$? \n" else echo -e "Parameter file not loaded \n return code=$? \n" exit 8 fi

I'm getting return code as 1 incase of failure

Comment: Many utilities return different exit codes on failure - see for example [`man curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) (section EXIT CODES).

Comment: @chhayavishwakarma `$?` refers to last executed statement, so you clobber it before it is echoed.

Answer (score 2):

You can return any 8-bit value, but only 0 means success, any other value is considered as a failure. In case of failure, the value itself has no predefined meaning you can choose any semantic you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Functions within a script and the script itself return an
>   exit status. The last command executed in the function or script
>   determines the exit status. Within a script, an exit nnn command may
>   be used to deliver an nnn exit status to the shell (nnn must be an
>   integer in the 0 - 255 range). ([source](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html))

Moreover, most programing language allow you to return a 8 bits status code.

In shell you can get the most recent status code with the variable `$?`.
And you can send one by using either `exit X` or `return X` where `-1<X<256`

Answer (score 0):

You can use any 8-bit exit status in shell script. Only 0 is consider as success all other are failure.